# Not last child mixin SASS

Tags: sass, mixins

Is it possible to turn this:

```
.redstripe p:not(last-child) {
  border-bottom:1px solid red;
}
```

Into a mixin so that I can apply it to any element and assign a child tag to it like:

```
@mixin redstripe (this.$children):not(last-child) {
  border-bottom:1px solid red;
}
```

And then apply:

```
div {
  @include redstripe(p);
}
```

What is the correct way to implement this?

Comment: I have been looking but cannot find anything that shows how to pass a tag as a parametre.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a general purpose mixin like you've described.

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://sassmeister.com/gist/218a068f6ba46d05e160)</kbd>

```
@mixin not-last-child($selector) {
  & #{$selector}:not(:last-child) {
    @content;
  }
}
```

We can pass it a selector string to use.

SCSS:

```
.thing {
  @include not-last-child('p') {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
.thing p:not(:last-child) {
  color: red;
}
```

[Sass Documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html)